# Prev/Next Buttons for Navigation Links

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm looking for a solution to have Previous and Next arrows that would cycle through the navigation links. Similar to the link below but when you click Prev Or Next you, it would take you to the next anchor in the nav li and load the new page.

```
 <div id="nav" class="text-spacing">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="/news.html" class="nav-button">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tourdates.html" class="nav-button">Tour Dates</a></li>
    <li><a href="/music.html" class="nav-button navSelected">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="/video" class="nav-button">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about" class="nav-button">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact" class="nav-button">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="arrow-left" class="slide-right"><a href="#" class="prev-button" title="Previous"><img src="images/arrow-left.png" alt="Left Arrow" width="25" height="48"></a></div>
<div id="arrow-right" class="slide-left"><a href="#" class="next-button" title="Next"><img         src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Right Arrow" width="25" height="48"></a></div

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
        var $next = $el.parent().next();

        if ($next.length == 0) $next = $('#nav li:first');

        $next.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');
    });


    $('.prev-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
        var $prev = $el.parent().prev();

        if ($prev.length == 0) $prev = $('#nav li:last');

        $prev.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/H2hjr/

**Home** | Music | Videos | Contact

Prev // Next

Comment: How are you expecting this to load the new page?

Comment: But your fiddle has different code with no anchors. Why don't you update it to at least include html with anchors in it even if you can't quite get the JS to work the way you want. Also, given that your sample html is quite short (and still will be after you add anchors) you should include it directly in the question (in addition to the fiddle).

Comment: I'm not fluent in javascript. I saw this code cycled through my nav links by changing the class. I'd love for the right and left arrow when clicked to go to the next link in the navigation and load it. Is that possible?

Comment: Updated code to show my nav and left and right arrow buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the `href` out of your links and use that to trigger `window.location.href` like so :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
        var $next = $el.parent().next();

        if ($next.length == 0) $next = $('#nav li:first');

        $next.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');

        // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
        window.location.href = $next.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');
    });


    $('.prev-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
        var $prev = $el.parent().prev();

        if ($prev.length == 0) $prev = $('#nav li:last');

        $prev.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');
        // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
        window.location.href = $prev.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');

    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Much appreciated!

Comment: You are most welcome. If this helps you out can you kindly accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, this is cycling between the first and last link for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: When you go to another page you need to set the current navigation item active otherwise you keep getting the same link.